# Given index i,j(j>=i) How to find the frequency of a A[j] at a subarray(i,j)?

Tags: c++, algorithm, cumulative-frequency

Given an array A of integers , I am trying to find out at a given position j , how many times A[j] occurs from every i=0 to i=j in A. I have devised a solution like below

```
map<int,int> CF[400005];
for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
{
   cin>>A[i];
   if(i!=0)
      CF[i-1] = CF[i];
   ++CF[i][A[i]]; 
}
```

than I can answer each query in logn time. But this procedure uses too much memory. Is there any way of doing it using less memory?

for more clarification , you can see the problem I am trying to solve http://codeforces.com/contest/190/problem/D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an array `B` of the same size as `A` and a map `C`. For each `j` in `B[j]` keep track of the number of occurrences of `A[j]` before `j`. In `C` keep track of the last occurrence of given element. Then you answer queries in constant time and it requires just O(n) memory.

Sorry for my pseudo-C++.

```
map<int,int> C;
int B[n]; // zeros

for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
{
    cin >> A[i];
    int prev = C[A[i]]; // let me assume it gives -1 if no element

    if (pref == -1) // this is the fist occurrence of B[i]
        B[i] = 1;
    else // if not the first, then add previous occurrences
        B[i] = B[prev] + 1 

    C[A[i]] = i; // keep track where the last info about A[j] is
}
```

Comment: Maybe i'm missing something, but if the last information about an element is out of the scope 0...j, then how will the query be performed? This seems perfect for lookup in the range 0...n, or maybe I'm heavily missing something?

Comment: Well, the question was to find out "how many times A[j] occurs from every i=0 to i=j in A". So the information about 0...j is sufficient. For more complex queries I would suggest a map of rank trees (map keys: A element values; tree kees: the positions of elements). Then we have O(log n) for each query and O(n) memory for the whole structure.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't give this too much time, but maybe instead of using a map will all the positions, use a list where for each element you put the points where the count of that element changes, something towards this:

```
struct count_info
{
    int index;
    int count;
    count_info* next;
};
...
std::map<int, count_info*> data;
```

, and then look up the right position in that queue. You still need one map, but then underneath you would only have a list of these pointers, and on query you look-up the A[i] in the map, and then go through the list while i > index && next && i < next->index. Of course, if logn is a must then this fails because the list look-up is n at worst.

Comment: Nice, but O(n) in the worst case. If however we take a rank trees instead of lists it should give O(log n) solution.

Comment: Yeah, this trivial fix suffers from O(n), well, a relatively easy addition would be heap sorting the `count_info*` by index, but I guess a rank tree on the other hand keeps all this kitchen stuff in itself. The author could specify what are the time / memory constraints on this task.